# Arraylist is not correctly parsed

Tags: android, mysql, arraylist

Hello i am facing a strange problem. I am trying to make a quiz app with questions and answers from the mysql database. I parse values as they can seem [here](http://my.chatapp.info/quiz/getf.php?id=3).

How i create the `List`:

```
@Override
    protected List<QuestionsList> doInBackground(String... params) {
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            setupDataToDB();
            outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
            bufferedWriter.write(StringGenerator.queryResults(nameValuePairs));
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
            jsonResult = StringGenerator.inputStreamToString(inputStream, QuestionsActivity.this);
            jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult.toString());
            Log.e("Response: ", jsonResult.toString());
            checkDisplayLanguage(langText);
            questionsLists = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                questionName = jsonChildNode.optString(Constants.QUESTION_NAME_JSON_NAME);
                Log.e("Question Name: ", questionName);
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonChildNode.optString(Constants.QUESTIONS_ANSWERS_ARRAY));
                for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray.length(); j++) {
                    jsonSecondChildNode = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                    answer1 = jsonSecondChildNode.optString("answer1");
                    answer2 = jsonSecondChildNode.optString("answer2");
                    answer3 = jsonSecondChildNode.optString("answer3");
                    iscorrect1 = jsonSecondChildNode.optString("iscorrect1");
                    iscorrect2 = jsonSecondChildNode.optString("iscorrect2");
                    iscorrect3 = jsonSecondChildNode.optString("iscorrect3");
                    question_answers = new ArrayList<>();
                    question_answers.add(answer1);
                    question_answers.add(answer2);
                    question_answers.add(answer3);
                    question_iscorrect = new ArrayList<>();
                    question_iscorrect.add(iscorrect1);
                    question_iscorrect.add(iscorrect2);
                    question_iscorrect.add(iscorrect3);
                    Log.e("Answers in for loop", question_answers.toString());
                    questionsLists.add(new QuestionsList(questionName, answersArray, question_iscorrect));
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return questionsLists;
    }
```

and the post execute looks like this:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<QuestionsList> lists) {
            super.onPostExecute(lists);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            position = 0;
            question.setText(lists.get(position).getName());
            answersArray = lists.get(position).getAnswers();
            ans1 = answersArray.get(position);
            ranswer1.setText(ans1);
        }
```

The debugging info look like this:

```
E/Question Name:: Where to look to find journal articles
E/Answers in for loop: [In the librarys catalog , , ]
E/Answers in for loop: [, In alphabetical list of healink , ]
E/Answers in for loop: [, , Databases available in the library's site]
E/Question Name:: What information we provide magazine
E/Answers in for loop: [Published research experiments current information, , ]
E/Answers in for loop: [, Lists information about people, addresses, organizations, ]
E/Answers in for loop: [, , Legislation, competitions]
E/Question Name:: What is the E/Answers in for loop: [Is the number used for the registration of periodical publications, , ]
E/Answers in for loop: [, Is the International Unique number used for registration of printed books, ]
E/Answers in for loop: [, , Is the International Unique number used for the recording of Publications mixed forms]
```

What am i doing wrong here and the arraylist is not correctly parsed?

Comment: why don't you use gson?

Comment: it does not have to do with how i parse since the data are fetched correctly. The question is about why it is getting the last item of the hashmap.

Comment: yes i did and it all seems correct

Comment: Are those constant really different?

Comment: of course they are

Comment: Can you post "Constants" file code ?

Comment: i just did see my edited question

Comment: put a breakpoint at         ans1 = hashMap.get(Constants.FIRST_ANSWER_POST_NAME); and debug it. see if you are getting values. If you are getting values then there would be problem with textviews. maybe your seting all values to same view.

Comment: I cannot understand why you need the second for loop, it looks redundant since you are not traversing the answers but just pulling them off by a constant you defined elsewhere, am I missing something?

Comment: how else am i going to put the keys and the values inside HashMap?

Comment: Well, you do understand that by doing so you ADD THE SAME DATA 3 times right?...
Also you have a duplicate on "iscorrect2"

Comment: why do i add the same data 3 times? and what do you mean by duplicate iscorrect2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is some sort of a typo or other error that needs debugging and going over slowly, not StackOverflow.

My personal bet is that your views (the ones kept in answer1, answer2 and answer3) are all one and the same view, because of a bug in initializing the activity. But frankly, this question should be closed, as it shows no specific problem.

Also, add:

```
question_answers = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

before the line:

```
question_answers.put(Constants.FIRST_ANSWER_POST_NAME, answer1);
```

Comment: what do you mean that it shows no specific problemm? Did you see the screenshot? How am i supposed to fix it?

Comment: Exactly. It shows a screenshot and around 10% of code. It's not a specific problem, it's a debugging task. For example I gave you a perfectly good answer - I have no idea if I pinpointed the specific problem, but it's one of many possible reasons of your code not working.

Comment: what is a perfectly good answer? because of a bug initilizing the activity? what does that mean? which bug is this? thats what i am asking for

Comment: @helldawg13 If you look at the code that initializes your views (I still think that the problem is you copy-pasted incorrectly and you initialize answer1, answer2 and answer3 to the same value) and it's fine, then the next hint would be to print out ans1, ans2 and ans3 in the ontaskcompletedataset (btw.: and start using variables instead of attributes). But, as you can see, I can offer you no answer - just debugging hints. Because there is no specific problem in your question.

Comment: @helldawg13: I have written 2 times. I will try once more. The code. That initializes attributes answer1, answer2 and answer3. Look at it. Probably it contains something like findViewById. Check the ids. Check the XML (or however you build the view - I have no idea) (and I have no idea, because you do not have a specific problem, you just want help with debugging)

Comment: i debugged the ans1, ans2, ans3 and the first 2 are empty and the third only gives me answer3 from last question. My question is why does it happen since the position is always 0?

Comment: Why? You said you debugged ans1, ans2 and ans3. If it's really so, then it's not a problem with XML.

Comment: ans1, ans2, ans3 are strings and answer1, answer2, answer3 are radiobuttons

Comment: how does it take the question in position 0 and hashmap in the last position? isnt that strange?

Comment: No. The real error is that you only make one hashmap for all the questions. So you have many QuestionsList objects, but they all share a single hasmap. So you are overwriting the answers.

Comment: @helldawg13 btw: the error you made stems mostly from the fact, that instead of using variables, you use attributes for everything. Don't do that, it's a terrible practice and leads to exactly the kind of error that you made.

Comment: how is this possible since the second for loop goes to jsonArray size which is always 3 so when the loop finishes goes to the next question and next answers array. please check the debugging info

Comment: please define what you mean attributes?

Comment: You know a "class", right? Well, there are two types of thingies inside a "class" are "attributes" (or "fields") and "methods".

Comment: "how is that possible"? Think about it: how many hashmaps do you create? You should create one per question. Instead, you only create one for all questions. Add something like `questions_answers = new HashMap<String, String>();` inside the questions loop, or something.

Comment: and you create one per all questions, because you tend to use attributes instead of variables :)

Comment: Yes now it creates it properly but it still takes only the answer3. ans1 and ans2 are empty? how is this possible?

Comment: This is exactly what I meant in the beginning. There is no specific problem here. There's a buggy program to debug. When I find one bug, you'll notice another. This is not a question for stackoverflow - you do not need an answer, you need someone who will teach you coding and debugging (nothing bad about it - it's just bad format for SO).

Comment: post all code (say, 10 lines) around the line that begins with `answer1 =`

Comment: which line that begins with answer1...it is in my question already

Comment: Then the other one, obviously? I wouldn't ask for the one that is already in the post? And you do have such line in the activity?... or?...

Comment: no i do not. everything you see in the question is where i use the ans1, ans2, ans3 and answer1, answer2, answer3.

Comment: i debugged the hashmap and it gives me this: E/Hash map: {answer3=, iscorrect2=, iscorrect1=000, answer2=, answer1=In the librarys catalog , iscorrect3=}...how is this possible ?

Comment: @helldawg13 In the previous version of the answer you had line with "answer1.setText" (now you call it ranswer1, or something). You MUST have code that initializes this attribute, and you do not show it (or you would have a null pointer exception). So no, you are NOT showing "everything".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107489/discussion-between-fdreger-and-helldawg13).

Answer (score 1):

There is one problem with your code.
You have to move

```
questionsLists.add(new QuestionsList(questionName, question_answers));
```

inside your inner `for loop`.
Because right now what you are doing is you are adding only last `question_answers` into your `questionsLists`. It should look like -

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
               ....
                for (int j=0;j<jsonArray.length();j++){
                    ....

            questionsLists.add(new QuestionsList(questionName, question_answers));
                }


            }
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Where are your views defined and instantiated - for answer1, answer2 and .. ?